# "I read the following in a book." or "I read the following from a book"

Tags: prepositions

What should we use after *following*?

> - I read the following **in** a book ...
> - I read the following **from** a book ...

Comment: Honestly, both are fine. As you can see from this Ngrams, the two have [a tumultuous history](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=following+in+a+book%2Cfollowing+from+a+book&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfollowing%20in%20a%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfollowing%20from%20a%20book%3B%2Cc0). However, I would not end either of the sentences at this point because if you mention something following, you should probably mention what it is. But I can understand if you had done this just for brevity.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I believe there's a nuance in meanings, but I cannot explain it.

Comment: **I read the following in a book**: this leads me to believe that you read it to yourself. **I read the following from a book**: this leads me to infer that you read aloud, to listeners.

Comment: @Davo. I see what you mean, but is this always true necessarily? Could there not be contexts where they mean the same such as those found in the Ngram?

Comment: @user178049 Heh, I know what you mean. I had had the same feeling at first, ergo my Ngramming of it. If you do figure it out, please let me know as well.

Comment: Please check this example to understand the context that I meant: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/119618/47521

Comment: This native US English speaker agrees with Davo.  "Read it **from** a book" isn't *wrong*, but it emphasizes the reading-out-loud aspect, rather than where the information was located.

Comment: (Southeastern US) In the linked context, "in" seems much more normal than "from". I don't think I've heard "from" outside of the context of church or academic lectures. "Today's reading is from the Gospel of Mark..."

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang, I don't believe that either phrasing insists that the reading was silent or aloud; this is just how I have understood it as a native American English speaker, 50+ years of age, having lived about half my life in the state of New York, and about half in the state of Georgia. What I've gleaned from reading, schooling, conversation, television watching, and radio listening leads me to make and stand by my comment above. I cannot point you to an official reference.

Comment: @Shannak. There are times when they mean the same and times when they could mean different things :). Actually, I feel like this question has appeared before, but for some reason, I cannot find it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read the following **in** a book ...

You can use *in* when telling someone about something you read. It is more likely that you are paraphrasing what you read.

> I read the following **from** a book ...

You can use *from* when telling someone about something you read, *word for word*.