# "I might as well sell it" Or "I should sell it"

Tags: modal-verbs

I read the following in a book.

> I use my car very little. There is no point in keeping it. I **might as well** sell it.

Is it Okay to replace "might as well" with "should"?

> I **should** sell it.

What is the difference in meaning between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sentences are fine, but they have slightly different meanings.

The first sentence shows less certainty or more reluctance than the second sentence. "Might as well" means that this action (selling it) is no worse than some other alternative (not selling it). The "as well" piece literally means "equally good".

"I should sell it" implies that selling it is the best option. You may still choose not to sell it (we often fail to do things that we really *should* do), but you are stating that this is the correct choice.

Depending on context, however, the meaning of these sentences can be very close. "Should" can also be used to signal reluctance, as in

> I really *should* give up cigarettes.

but it doesn't have to.